# Problems setting Hyper-V permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I am using a Windows 2012 Hyper-V server to host some test PCs.  Our support personnel should be able to take snapshots of these machines and roll a test machine back to a specific snapshot, but they should not have any other permissions.  I have followed the directions in [this](http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/delegate-access-control-and-management-in-hyper-v) article and, on suggestion of another article have added the specific AD group to the local Hyper-V Administrators group, but whenever one of them attempts to connect to the server to take a snapshot, they get an error stating that they do not have permission to connect to that server.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but at this point I'm at a loss as to what that would be.  Can anyone tell me how to properly set these permissions?

edit:  Per request I am attaching a screenshot of the permissions I have set for this group.

[image]

Comment: Are they attempting to connect using RDP? Or some third party remote control program. The reason I ask is to determine if you know it is a credential issue or a server setting disallowing the user group to connect.

Comment: They can successfully connect through RDP.  They are failing to connect VIA the Hyper-V manager so they can make snapshots.

Comment: O.k., so they have the credentials, they just don't have the correct permission if I am reading this link right.     'Give the group a name then click OK. I’m going to call mine Read-Only, because I will use it to give users only read access to VM’s. So everyone that is part of this group and connects to my Hyper-V server using the Hyper-V Manager console, **they will not be able to change VM’s and Hyper-V settings, or even power on or off VM’s**.'     Did you also set their permission to READ ONLY?

Comment: No.  I was only using that article as a guideline.  I gave them the permissions that I would assume they would need for manipulating snapshots.

Comment: O.K., great. Can you screen cap what permission in the HyperV manager you are allowing this group? I only have access to a 2008 HyperV server until Thursday when I can get on *my* 2012 HyperV server so I probably can't comb over them, but I'm sure someone else on the site will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users need at least one permission to connect: Read Service Configuration.
If you add this, you should be fine.

Which you can also reread in the article you mentioned:

> Don’t close the window yet, because there is a definition, a very
>   important one, that if you don’t enable, your users will not be able
>   to connect to the Hyper-V service. They will get message that you read
>   at the beginning of this guide. The definition is called Read Service
>   Configuration. Check the box next to it then hit OK;

Comment: I'll give you the answer even though I can't test it.  My managers decided to move away from hyper-v because the network department is scared to learn anything new.